# How handle the UIPageViewController VCs rotating by viewWillTransitionToSize func?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, viewwilltransitiontosize

I try to create UIPageVC with 3 pages. All is good, but when I rotate device and after this change page I will see that rotates only page, which is settled in PageVC in rotate moment.

How rotate other 2 VCs, when I rotate any page?

Maybe I can do this in PageVC class?

I used **Swift 4.0**, so I must use `viewWillTransitionToSize` func.

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding the `viewWillTransitionToSize` function and forward the message to all of your view controllers contained in your UIPageViewController.

```
fileprivate var yourViewControllers = [UIViewController]()    

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    yourViewControllers.forEach({ $0.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator) })
}
```

Comment: You mean that I should to call all pages in UIPageVC overrides func?